# How to save a part of a HTML page to the user's computer

Tags: javascript, html, save

I want to let a user save a pre-defined part of a website to their computer in probably pdf format with some different css styles applied.

I have done the same for printing, but I couldn't find any examples for saving.

How would I go about doing this?

The specific parts are in their respective divs and ids.

Thanks

Comment: you will need a library that generates the pdf. If you are working with php, you can try [fPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a library to do this.

depending on the language you're using, there's a lot of possibilities. Even google chrome itself print pdf from html.

Give us more details about your project